# Finding the minimum and median values in a column if they match criteria using vba

Tags: vba, excel, criteria, median, minimum

I have a sheet with a load of data which corresponds to a certain group, in this case groups A, B, C, D and E.

I would like to run a macro that would be on another sheet and would find the minimum and median values that correspond with what's in the first column of the table.

[image]

Using the image, I'd like to run a macro that would look at the value in cell F2 and then give me the minimum value in column C that has "A" in the adjacent cell and so on for each group. Similarly I would like the median to then be calculated for each group

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried anything and hit a snag? I imagine there are many examples online. You probably need array formulae.

Comment: I'm in a good mood so have suggested an answer below, but in future you should show some effort first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In G2 and down

```
=min(if(b$2:b$20=f2,c$2:c$20))
```

In H2 and down

```
=median(if(b$2:b$20=f2,c$2:c$20))
```

Adjust ranges as necessary.

Enter both as array formulas - use Ctrl + Shift + Enter to confirm. If done correctly curly brackets will surround the formula.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message! I'm looking for it to be written in vba code rather than excel formulas. So the report can be fully automated. Nothing I've tried so far has worked!

Comment: You could record a macro while you enter the formulas? I'll take a look later when I have a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an UDF, though I would go with the answer already given.

Func `GetMinMedianIf`:

Returns either the minimum or median, according to arg3, for the range specified in arg1, where the value in the first column of the range (arg1) matches that of the arg2 range.

1. Arg1 `rng`: The entire data range
2. Arg2 `searchValue`: The range containing the value to match on e.g. D2 (which is A)
3. Arg3 `MinMedian`: The calculation to perform. `Min` for Minimum, Median for Median

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TEST() '<== This is just a test sub to run
    Debug.Print GetMinMedianIf([A2:B16], [F2], "Min") ' or "Median"
End Sub
```

**UDF:**

```
 Public Function GetMinMedianIf(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal searchValue As Range, ByVal MinMedian As String) As Long
    'MinMedian args: "Min" for Min; "Median" for Median
    Dim arr(), i As Long, counter As Long

    If searchValue.Cells > 1 Then
        GetMinMedianIf = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    arr = rng.Value
    Dim arr1()
    ReDim arr1(0 To UBound(arr, 1) - 1)

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) = searchValue Then
            arr1(counter) = arr(i, 2)
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve arr1(0 To counter)

    Select Case MinMedian
    Case "Min"
        GetMinMedianIf = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(arr1)
    Case "Median"
        GetMinMedianIf = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(arr1)
    End Select
End Function
```

---

Usage in sheet

[image: UDF]

Comment: @huw96 You can use the above function